# Is there a positive integer with $2010$ distinct positive integer factors?

Tags: factoring

Suppose that, $$f(n)=(\text{ the number of distinct positive integer factors of $n$ including $1$ and $n$ } )$$

Is there a positive integer $m$ such that $f(m)=2010$  ?

How can conclude about the existence of a positive integer $n$ such that $f(n)$ is equal to any desired positive integer?

Comment: If $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then the number of divisors of $n$ is $\prod (a_i+1)$...

Comment: The smallest such number is $1\,045\,930\,388\,979\,331\,576\,627\,200$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$.  An integer factor of $n$ will be of the form $\prod p_i^{j_i}$ where $0 \le j_i \le k_i$.  To "choose" a factor we must "choose" a power for each prime $p_i$ and for that prime we will have $k_i + 1$ choices.

So $f(n) = \prod(k_i + 1)$.

So the simplest answer would be $f(p^{2009}) = 2010$ for a prime $p$, but any $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ where $\prod(k_i + 1)= 2010$ will do.  As $2010 = 2*3*5*67$, I think the smallest such number would be $n = 2^{66}*3^4*5^2*7$.  At least I think that is the smallest such number.

Answer (score 3):

Example $$m=2^{2009}$$

For all $n$, note that $2^{n-1}$ has $n$ distinct integer factors. Thus for all $n$, such $m$ exists that $f(m)=n$.